# Print and raise exception not showing when using multiprocessing with Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, multiprocessing

So I know that you need to put your function in a separate python file when doing multiprocessing with Jupyter. E.g.

```
def trial_hello():
    print('Hello World')
```

or

```
def trial_excp():
    raise Exception
```

But when I import these into the Jupyter notebook, set up the Process, use start and join, I don't see the expected output and nothing is shown.  If I call the functions without using multiprocessing, I see the expected output.

So do you know what I need to add for this to work?

Edit:

Providing the code I used in the main notebook:

```
from ipynb.fs.full.trial import trial_hello
from multiprocessing import Process

p1 = Process(target=trial_hello)
p2 = Process(target=trial_hello)
p3 = Process(target=trial_hello)

p1.start()
p2.start()
p3.start()

p1.join()
p2.join()
p3.join()
```

Comment: Show the complete reproducible code (here it includes how you setup the process)

Comment: @Charchit Just added the complete code

Comment: When I run your code (more or less) under Jupyter Lab (Windows), then all print output to *stdout* or *stderr* generated by child processes is routed instead to the window that is opened when Jupyter Lab is first launched rather than to below the cell being executed. I believe you are just looking in the wrong place.